# SharePoint 2010 Error: List does not exist

Tags: sharepoint-2010

When trying to add or edit tasks as any user other than domain admins on my SharePoint 2010 site, I get the following error:
List does not exist.
The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.

Comment: Can you have a look at the Logs in the 14 folder and see if there is some more info at the same timestamp as when the error occurs? It would seem like a permission issue, but har to say without more details.

Also, try to add one of the other users to the site owners group and see if that helps. It would isolate the problem a bit.

Comment: Thanks @Justin and @Joe, of all the hits I found for this error message, this one helped me solve my Sharepoint problem. There's a guid on the error page (for correlation) and searching for it in the logs under 14 led to a useful and immediately applicable error message (from Sharepoint? who knew?) that I used to solve my problem.